# two foreach loop on if statement

Tags: php, loops, if-statement, foreach

Wondering if it's possible to have a foreach loop call on if statement like this :

```
if (class_exists('WooCommerce')) { 
    foreach (array_combine($val1, $val2) as $key => $row_values)
}
else {
    foreach ( $val1 as $key => $row_values ) 
}

{ begin of loop code
```

What I'm trying to do is to have a foreach loop if woocommerce plugin is active and to have another foreach loop if woocommerce isn't active.

Comment: no idea what you mean. you already have two foreaches in your if() statement.

Comment: No. You can assign the array just to a variable inside the if/else and then use the assigned array in the foreach loop.

Comment: Can you share with us what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible the way you try it, since that is invalid syntax.

What you *can* do is something like that:

```
<?php
$iterationArray = class_exists('WooCommerce') ? array_combine($val1, $val2) : $val1;
foreach ($iterationArray as $key => $row_values) {
    // begin of loop code
} // end loop
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do if a condition before the loop to assign the variables you will use to loop, just like this:

```
if ( class_exists( 'WooCommerce' ) ) {
    $newVal = array_combine($val1, $val2);
} else {
    $newVal = $val1;
}

foreach ( $newVal as $key => $row_values ) {
    // do stuff
}
```

The result will be the same as what you were trying to do. But the syntax you proposed in your question is not supported in PHP, and can be worked around with the way proposed above.